# About Java ServerSocket Accept: busy-wating?

Tags: java, serversocket

i'm reading the TCP/IP Socket in Java, about the serversocket, it says

> When we call accept() on that ServerSocket
>   instance, if a new connection is pending, accept() returns immediately; otherwise it blocks
>   until either a connection comes in or the timer expires, whichever comes first. This allows
>   a single thread to handle multiple connections. Unfortunately, **the approach requires that
>   we constantly poll all sources of I/O**, and that kind of “busy waiting” approach again introduces
>   a lot of overhead from cycling through connections just to find out that they have
>   nothing to do.

As I understand it, should this be "notified" when a connection comes thus should not be "busy waiting"? Did i misunderstand something...?

-----------------*EDIT*----------------------

The whole paragraph is as below:

> Because of these complications, some programmers prefer to stick with a single-threaded
>   approach, in which the server has only one thread, which deals with all clients—not sequentially,
>   but all at once. Such a server cannot afford to block on an I/O operation with any
>   one client, and must use nonblocking I/O exclusively. Recall that with nonblocking I/O, we specify the maximum amount of time that a call to an I/O method may block (including zero).
>   We saw an example of this in Chapter 4, where we set a timeout on the accept operation
>   (via the setSoTimeout() method of ServerSocket). When we call accept() on that ServerSocket
>   instance, if a new connection is pending, accept() returns immediately; otherwise it blocks
>   until either a connection comes in or the timer expires, whichever comes first. This allows
>   a single thread to handle multiple connections. Unfortunately, the approach requires that
>   we constantly poll all sources of I/O, and that kind of “busy waiting” approach again introduces
>   a lot of overhead from cycling through connections just to find out that they have
>   nothing to do

Comment: The statement as quoted is drivel. Is that really an accurate and complete quotation? And what from? He talks about blocking and single threading/busy-waiting all in the same sentence. They are mutually incompatible. Unless he means using really short timers, in which case he should say so.

Comment: It's in the first part of Chapter 5 NIO, <TCP/IP Socket in Java, Second Edition> book. The whole paragraph is telling that NIO select is more efficient than ServerSocket accept. i just did catch it...

Comment: Is that the one by K.L. Calvert? It's really most unclear, and it's quite incorrect to suggest that you can block for a non-zero time with non-blocking I/O ... unless he means select(), but the part about polling suggests that he's never heard of it. Very poor quality. There are better books around, even mine ;-).

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly nonsense, even in the entire quotation. *Either* you are using blocking I/O, in which case you need a thread per connection, and another per accept() loop, *or* you are using  non-blocking I/O, in which case you have select(), *or,* from Java 7, you are using Asynchronous I/O, in which case it is all callbacks into completion handlers. In none of these cases do you need to poll or busy-wait.

I *think* he must be referring to using blocking mode with very short timeouts, but it's really most unclear.